# investigating and testing temporally overlapping data points in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, temporal-difference

This is a two-part question that first asks how to query some data I have in R, and secondly, asks what might be the appropriate statistical operations to test any perceived relationships between variables that might be found.

(I originally posted a different version of this question on StackOverflow and it was suggested to bring the second part of that question here to CrossValidated. You can find the original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74746567/structuring-and-cross-referencing-time-bound-data-points-in-r/74747300?noredirect=1#comment132085900_74747300) if necessary.)

I am interested in how people use their speech, body, hands, and something else (called evidentality) to show their viewpoint. People can do this simultaneously. I have data that comes from annotations from a video of a person talking. The data looks like this (this is a sample):

| channel | start.time | stop time | vp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| speech | 0 | 9.719 | N |
| speech | 9.719 | 11.735 | EE |
| hands | 0.264 | 2.032 | N |
| body | 26.514 | 28.264 | CH1 |
| evidential | 82.316 | 82.702 | self |
| evidential | 10.354 | 11.666 | other |
| hands | 80.251 | 82.719 | CH2 |
| body | 27.564 | 30.819 | CH1 |
| speech | 25.621 | 27.693 | N |

the 'channel' column represents these four different modes in which viewpoint can be displayed, the 'vp' column represents 'viewpoint' and the values within refer to a specific point of view (N= narrator, CH1 = character 1) etc.

I have put this data into a `data.frame` in `R`, and have used `ggplot` to visualize the overall sequences, it looks like this:

[image]

Each row shows a channel, and each colored bar in the channel represents the values in the 'vp' column.

What I want to be able to do, is find out which 'vp' values tend to co-occur or not co-occur across channels. To do that, I need to be able to specify a specific 'vp' value in one channel and generate a list of the values in one or more other channels.

e.g. "for every N in the speech channel, what are the values that co-occur with it in the other channels?"

One such example comes from the data in the above table, in the 4th row, there is a CH1 value in the body channel and the final row, there is an N value in the speech channel that overlaps with. How can I query one of them to successfully find the other?

The second part of this question concerns how to evaluate the significance of any co-occurrences or lack of co-occurrence that I may find. Perhaps that question has to wait until I can do the above and find some observable trends in the data. At this point, I don't have more specific research questions other than 'what co-occurs?'

But let's say I observe, what appears to be a correlation between 'N' in the body channel and 'CH1' in the hands channel. How would I test the significance of that correlation? These are nominal variables, and I suppose either could serve as the independent variable. Would something like an ANOVA be the way to go?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be most appreciated.